# Raphael.js - bbox is too big using a custom font

Tags: javascript, text, fonts, raphael, bounding-box

I have the problem, that when I create a text with a custon font, that the bounding-box is too big. When I use standard-font everything is allright.
Anyone an idea?

I worked it out!
Apparently raphael.js can not detect the width of a text, when only @font-face is used.
I had to register the font with Raphael.registerFont().

Comment: please answer your own question for the benefit of others, don't just update your question with the answer.